# Get property values from a string using Reflection

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reflection

I am new to this concept of reflection and finding problem in retrieving property value from a string. E.g.

I have a class Employee with following properties :

```
public string Name {get;set;}
public int Age {get;set;}
public string EmployeeID {get;set;}

string s = "Name=ABCD;Age=25;EmployeeID=A12";
```

I want to retrieve the value of each property from this string and create a new object of Employee with those values retrieved from the string for each field.

Can anyone please suggest how it can be done using reflection ??

Comment: Separate this into different tasks - first you need to parse your string, splitting it into different properties. How far have you got so far?

Comment: I have tried to split it with char ";" but still i am not able able to understand how to work with the concept of reflection.

Comment: So get as far as you can before you hit reflection (splitting into names and values) and then you can edit your question to be specific to the data you've got at that point... basically, narrow the question down as far as you can.

Answer (score 0):

//may be..

string s = "Name=ABCD;Age=25;EmployeeID=A12";

```
        string[] words = s.Split(';');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            string[] data = word.Split('=');
            string _data = data[1];
            Console.WriteLine(Name);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, This will workout to retrieve the needed parameters. It is common approach to retrieve data from string. Is this related to reflection?

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how you maybe could do it

it used Reflection like you wanted ^^

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace replace
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var s = "Name=ABCD;Age=25;EmployeeID=A12";
            var list = s.Split(';');

            var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var probVal = item.Split('=');
                dic.Add(probVal[0], probVal[1]);
            }

            var obj = new MyClass();

            PropertyInfo[] properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dic[property.Name]);
                if (property.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                    property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ToInt32(dic[property.Name]));
                //else if (property.PropertyType== typeof(yourtype))
                //    property.SetValue(obj, (yourtype)dic[property.Name]);
                else
                    property.SetValue(obj, dic[property.Name]);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Age);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.EmployeeID);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }

        public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    }
}
```